jenkins not exposing in browser in custom nat network
I had configured my vagrantfile with my custom nat network for some use to connect the remote servers but the problem is I am not able to access the jenkins at port 8080 on browser
debug trials done:

configured firewall for the port 8080
tried forwarded port also config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
systemctl restart jenkins

here is my code of the vagrant file
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", virtualbox__intnet: "CustomNatNetwork"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "server1"
  end
end


I'd be happy if someone can help me resolve the error.
